# powershell script to launch app using Corporate PROXY server authentication?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, proxy, environment-variables, windows-11

I'm trying to launch the popular flashcard app Anki2 on my work laptop that runs Windows 11.
Unfortunately the app is unable to connect to the ankiweb.net servers and *syncronize* my progress with that of my other mobile devices. I've done some digging and tried these two scripts -- only the .bat works, the powershell doesn't, why?
Can you give me some pointers please, so that I can fix it?

`anki-proxy.bat`:

```
@echo off &SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /p USERNAME=<myuser>
set /p PASSWORD=<passwrd>


set "https_proxy=http://<myuser>:<passwrd>@mycompanyproxy-address:9090"
cd "C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Programs\Anki"
start anki.exe
pause
```

`anki2-proxy.ps1`:

```
$proxyCreds=get-credential -username $env:username -message "Please put your Proxy password: "

Set-Variable http_proxy="http://{$proxyCreds.USERNAME}:{$proxyCreds.PASSWORD}@mycompanyproxy-address:9090"

Start "C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Programs\Anki\anki.exe"
```

In the latter case I get the usual:

> Error details: ⁨error sending request for url (): error trying to connect: tcp connect error

but in the former, the synchronisation works and I'm able to proceed with the learning.

Comment: FYI, in your batch file you should always use the `/D` option with the `CD` unless you have already specifically defined a working drive and directory. Also you can refine that location further by using a built-in environment variable, i.e. ```CD /D "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Anki"```. Although for your use above, you could probably have just done it without, and defined the working directory in the `Start` command line ```Start /D "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Anki" anki.exe```. Also, i'ts likely that you don't need to change directory anyhow, ```Start "" "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Anki\anki.exe"```!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Set-Variable` call with the following:

```bash
$env:https_proxy = "http://$($proxyCreds.UserName):$($proxyCreds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)@mycompanyproxy-address:9090"
```

- You must define an [*environment* variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) (`$env:https_proxy`), which [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) does *not* do (it creates variables that are visible to the PowerShell session only, not also to *child processes*).<sup>[1]</sup>

  - As an aside: `Set-Variable` requires the variable *name* and *value* to be passed as *separate arguments*, not as single argument with `=` as the separator (something like `Set-Variable var="value"` defines a variable whose verbatim name is `var=value`, and which has *no value* (`$null`)).
  - Only in direct [variable assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables) is the  variable name (which must be prefixed with `$`) separated from its value with `=` (e.g., `$var = 'value'`)
- To embed *expressions* such as `$proxyCreds.UserName` inside `"..."`, an [expandable (double-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), you must enclose them in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), as shown above.

  - For a summary of the syntax and rules of PowerShell's string expansion (interpolation), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).
- You need an - inherently insecure - *plain-text* representation of your password, which the `.Password` property of a [`[pscredential]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCredential) instance (as returned by [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential)) does *not* provide - it returns a [`[securestring]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString) instance.

  - To obtain the plain-text form of the password, you must call `.GetNetworkCredential()` and access the `.Password` property on the resulting [`System.Net.NetworkCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Net.NetworkCredential) instance.

---

<sup>[1] Note that there is *no* such distinction in `cmd.exe` (batch files): all variables are implicitly and invariable *environment* variables.</sup>

Comment: thanks for all your explanation, unfortunate even after saving the changes you suggested, I still get: `Error details: ⁨error sending request for url (): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Impossibile stabilire la connessione.` which corresponds to a timeout error `os error 10060`. the .bat file doesn't give this problem, though it doesn't hide credentials.

Comment: @WobblyWindows, there was a typo in the environment variable name in your PowerShell code, which I didn't notice and also initially used in this answer: `http_proxy` instead of `https_proxy`. I've updated the answer to use `https_proxy`; please try again.

Comment: tried it, still not working. This time, however the error I'm getting is different. `Please check your internet connection. Error details: ⁨error sending request for url (): error trying to connect: dns error: Host unknown. (os error 11001)⁩`

Comment: Here's more, from the prompt: 
`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ankiweb.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /shared/updates/1463041493,1771074083?v=3 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000019012DA8340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))) update check failed`

Comment: @WobblyWindows, if the batch file works (and no additional environment variables are required beyond the one named `https_proxy`), the implication is that the _value_ of this variable in the PowerShell script is not correctly constructed. Insert `echo "%https_proxy"` in your batch file to echo the correct value, then compare it to the value of `$env:https_proxy` in your PowerShell script. I know nothing about ankiweb.net and its proxy configuration, so I can't help there, but likely culprits are an incorrect host name, port, or credentials.

Comment: still can't get it to work, but thanks for all your suggestions @mklement0

Comment: I'm sorry to hear it; you're welcome. Have you tried comparing the echoed URLs to see if they match?